# Windows is displaying the correct time, but lot's of websites say I'm an hour ahead

Tags: windows-10, time

My computer is displaying the correct time, but when looking at time.is, or other websites that require your computer time to be correct, I get this message.

`Your clock is 1 hour and 6.9 seconds ahead.`

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but this is a new PC.

This is keeping me from working as the software my company uses to clock time requires the time to be accurate.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is your timezone accurate?  While it may be right, you could possibly have the wrong time zone with an adjusted time.

Comment: My timezone was not accurate.  When I changed it, my time moved up an hour, and windows does not display the correct time anymore.

Comment: Another thing to check for is Daylight saving time.  With Windows 10, there should be an option to adjust that you can turn on and off.  Make sure that is also **on**.  If all else fails, try to set the time manually instead of letting Windows do it automatically.  Let me know if anything helps.

Comment: Daylight saving time was turned on.  I turned it off, and the time on windows is correct now.  I'm still getting an error about the time being incorrect though.  Could it be something to do with the bios?

Comment: You want that checked **On**.  Another thing you could do is check your BIOS settings as you mentioned and make sure they match up as well.  You may even be able to set it manually.  Reboot.

Comment: try this: https://www.organicweb.com.au/20209/general-technology/windows10-time/

Comment: Am I missing something here?  You say, “My timezone was not accurate. When I changed it, my time moved up an hour, and Windows does not display the correct time anymore.”  So that means that the website(s) that say that your clock is an hour ahead are correct, right?  So set the clock to the correct time.  (You do have permission to change the clock, right?)

Comment: Have you by chance tried synchronizing the clock with a time server in Windows?

Comment: The time on windows is accurate.  I can't see that the time is wrong.  Other websites are telling me the clock is wrong however.  As an example, time.is tells me that my clock is an hour ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your PC is set to correct region and time zone. 
To do this, go to Control Panel (You might need to type ‘Control Panel’ on some version of Windows.) Then click on Region. Check each tabs (Formats, Location and Administrative) that settings match your current location and time zone. (You might need to restart if required.)

After that, go back to Control Panel. Then click on Date and Time.
Focus on Date and Time tab. Ensure that your Time zone is correct. 
Finally, go to Internet Time tab. Then click on ‘Change settings…’ button. You will see Internet Time Settings window appeared. Ensure that ‘Synchronize with an Internet time server’ check box is checked. Click on ‘Update now’ button to synchronize your PC date and time with your selected server.  If synchronization complete successfully, you will get message “The clock was successfully synchronized with  on  at .”
(These steps might need administrator privilege and might need to restart to take effects)

Your tabs might unavailable if your computer is part of a domain. 
(Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ef0cdb1a-8f8a-4b8e-bbe5-44566223a4bc/how-to-sync-system-clock-with-internet-time-in-windows-7?forum=w7itprogeneral)